# a group homomorphism between $\mathbb{Z}_n$ and $\mathbb{Z}_m$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

Let $m,n,d$ be positive integers.find the sufficient and necessary condition that $f:\mathbb{Z}_n=\{0,1,\ldots,n-1\}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}_m$ such that $f(x)=dx$ is a group homomorphism.

i tried to solve this with noticing that $f$ is uniquely determined just with $f(1)$ and we know that $O(f(1)=d)|O(1)=m$ so we must have $\frac{n}{(n,d)}|m$.

i think it is sufficient condition,but how to prove that?

thanks a lot

Comment: assuming you mean $\mathbb Z_n = \mathbb Z / n \mathbb Z$? not saying what you wrote is bad, just that people use $\mathbb Z_n$ for many different things so it's nice to be clear which you mean

Comment: @neptun that's true.

Comment: @neptun $\Bbb Z_n$ is safer than $\Bbb Z_p$.

Comment: One counter example of your statement  $\frac{n}{(n,d)}|m$ is $n=6,d=4,m=8$

Answer (score 1):

At first we should explicit the definition of $f$ . You say $f(x)=dx$ this means multiplication by $d$ act on the **set** $ \{0,1,...,n-1\}$ and then you consider the answers$\mod m$.
For example if $n=5,m=10,d=3$ then $f(4)=3*4 \pmod {10} = 2$ .
For checking  homomorphism of $f$ we should show : $$f(x +_n y)=f(x) +_m f(y)$$
I wrote $+_n$ and $+_m$ to mention the difference between operations of $\mathbb Z_n$ and $\mathbb Z_m$.
It's equal to say $$d(x +_n y) \equiv d(x + y) \pmod m\quad \forall x,y \in \mathbb Z_n$$ and by congruence theorems if $\gcd(m,d)=k$ we can cancel $d$ from both sides and get $$x +_n y \equiv x + y \pmod {m/k}\quad \forall x,y \in \mathbb Z_n$$
Set $x=1 , y=n-1$ hence we should have $\frac{m}{k}|n$ .
And if $\frac{m}{k}|n$ there is no difference between $x +_n y \mod \frac{m}{k}$ and $x+y \mod \frac{m}{k}$ .
Therefore $f$ is a homomorphism if and only if $\frac{m}{\gcd(m,d)}|n$ .